# "python manage.py dbshell" for other DB Command-Line Clients (Django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database, dbclient

I read the documentation about [**"dbshell"**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/django-admin/#dbshell).

Then, it says:

> Runs the command-line client for the database engine specified in your
> ENGINE setting, with the connection parameters specified in your USER,
> PASSWORD, etc., settings.
>
> - For PostgreSQL, this runs the psql command-line client.
> - For MySQL, this runs the mysql command-line client.
> - For SQLite, this runs the sqlite3 command-line client.
> - For Oracle, this runs the sqlplus command-line client.

So, as the documentation says, with the command below, it's possible to run(open) **DB Command-Line Clients** for **PostgreSQL**, **MySQL**, **SQLite** and **Oracle**:

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

My question:

With the command below, is it possible to run(open) **DB Command-Line Clients** for other databases such as **MSSQL(SQL Server)**, **MongoDB**, etc?

```
python manage.py dbshell
```

Answer (score 0):

**No**. At this moment (24<sup>th</sup> June, 2022) django doesn't support any other database backend. **The [source code](https://github.com/django/django/tree/4.0.5/django/db/backends) has only backend for PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite and Oracle**.

However, there is a [MSSQL backend](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django) from Microsoft. It has all the bells and whistles.

For MongoDB, I haven't seen any backend that implemented `client.py`. You might want to request a feature to [this project](https://github.com/django-nonrel/mongodb-engine).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, **Yes**, it's possible to run(open) **the DB Command-Line Client** for **MSSQL(SQL Server)** when connecting **Django** and **MSSQL** with [**mssql-django**](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-django).

This is **the MSSQL Command-Line Client** as shown below:

[image]